# Kotlin || How to distinguish the view id from onClick() like switch statement in Android?

Tags: java, android, onclick, kotlin

As we know in **`Android`** we are using the **`switch`** statement to distinct the `view` like below, We used to `implement` **`View.OnClickListener`** to get `onClick` interface method to perform any task

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgBack:

              ///DO SOME THING HERE

                break;

            case R.id.btnSubmit:

                ///DO SOME THING HERE

                break;
        }
    }
```

Same thing i am using in **`Kotlin`** , by implement the  **`View.OnClickListener`** and getting its overrided method like below

```
class FeedBackActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

 /// HOW CAN I USE THE SWITCH STATEMENT TO DISTINGUISH THE VIEW CLICK 

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.feed_back_screen)

        imgBack.setOnClickListener(this)


    }

}
```

In above code i want to use the same **`switch`** to distinguish the different view click. How can i archive this in **`Kotlin`**

I know there is another way to perform the click listener in **`Kotlin`** like below

```
MY_VIEW.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"I have clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

But i want to use the same interface in **`Kotin`** which we are using the **`Android`**.Please help me to short out from this problem

Comment: i think this [link](https://antonioleiva.com/when-expression-kotlin/) may help you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`when` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression). It is the equivalent of Java's `switch`. Example code:

```
when(view.id) {
    R.id.imgBack -> {/* code goes here */}
    R.id.btnSubmit -> {/* you can omit the braces if there is only a single expression */}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this **use when** :- , when expressions in Kotlin can do everything you can do with a switch and much more.

Actually, with when you can substitute the most complex if/else you can have in your code.

for more info [visit this site](https://antonioleiva.com/when-expression-kotlin/)

```
 when (view.id) {
    R.id.home -> perform your action here
    R.id.search -> perform your action here
    R.id.settings -> perform your action here
    else -> perform action
}
```

Comment: follow this [link](https://antonioleiva.com/when-expression-kotlin/)@RavindraKushwaha